# NIS passwd file always empty

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, nis

I've setup NIS on Centos 5.3 following the fairly sketchy documentation online, it seems to be working pretty well, **however** whenever I run `ypcat passwd`, either from the server or the client, no entries are ever returned.

There's definitely some entries in the /etc/passwd file on the server and I've run ypinit, as well as tried running `make` in /var/yp to rebuild the database.

`ypcat hosts` works fine, I get the hosts file from the server, I don't get any errors in the log. Both machines are setup to in nsswitch.conf to read from NIS as well as files.

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: You might consider using likewise open for authentication.  I have NIS in my production environment and personally I find it to be hell, but I am sure others use it successfully.  You can find people's opinions on the topic in other serverfault questions.

Comment: I'd add another vote for not using NIS. NIS is falling out of favour. Unless you have legacy servers, you'd be better off using LDAP. There's a lot more documentation and more people are using it and have experience of it.

Comment: I'm not planning on using it in production, just in a smallish test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this is a bit of a facepalm moment, NIS doesn't show any users with UIDs <500 in it's passwd export, I hadn't added any non-privileged users to the VM I was testing it on. all works fine now :-S

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured /etc/nsswitch.conf? It should contain lines such as:

```
passwd:     files nis
group:      files nis
```

Comment: Yeah - it's exactly as you've written it there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ypcat passwd.byname
```

or

```
ypcat passwd.byuid
```

Also, on your NIS server are there db files for the passwd map?

Comment: Both return nothing, there are passwd.byname and passwd.byuid files in /var/yp/internal, also more annoyingly, when I make a change to the passwd file and then run `make` in the /var/yp directory, the passwd files **do** get updated, however there's still nothing returned from ypcat.

Might also add I tried adding "+::::::" to the end of the passwd file with no effect.

Comment: Are you sure it is grabbing your /etc/passwd for building the map?  Have you queried the actual db files created in /var/yp/internal/passwd.byname?